# Dual SSH connection to Linux Desktop RDP

Tags: networking, ssh, rdp, ssh-tunnel

How can I explain this....

I have a remote ubuntu linux system that has it's desktop shared at a third party site.  This system has a dynamic ip address, so I have setup a reverse ssh tunnel across the internet that connects back to a secure system in our network room.

Now from my desk I would like to connect to the secure system and have it forward my RDP request to the remote system.

All these systems are running Linux.  So I thought I could use ssh from my desk to tunnel the connection to the server in the network room and have it redirect the port to the remote system on the internet.  That doesn't work.

How can I solve this issue of RDPing to a remote system?

Here is an example:

```
+--------+    request              +---------+  Reverse ssh Tunnel   +--------+
|        |  -------------------->  | Server  |  <------------------> |        |
|TightVNC|              Static IP  |  Proxy  |  Port            Port | Remote |
| Client |  <--------------------  |         |  50000           5900 | Client |
+--------+    response             +---------+                       +--------+
```

I think I might need netcat on the Server to listen on some port e.g. 50001 and forward it to port 50000.

The reverse tunnel from the remote server is setup to establish a reverse tunnel from the server on port 50000 and redirect it to port 5900 on the remote machine.  I know this works but I need the TightVNC client to connect to the Server Proxy and have a bidirectional pipe.

Comment: Does your problem boil down to forwarding ports from an SSH client (as you are using a "reverse SSH tunnel") or to forwarding across more than one SSH hop (SSH client - *secure system* - *remote ubuntu* - RDP server) ?

Comment: It sure sounds to me that you have reached the point where you should stop trying to use SSH, and spend some time on setting up a full VPN (eg OpenVPN).

Answer (score 1):

The SSH tunnel you have now will only let you connect via SSH, is that correct? What you would need to do is set up another tunnel that will forward your connection to the RDP port instead. I would need more information about the ports you're using to give you a more detailed anser.

Another answer to a question you didn't ask, though, is that it's possible to have a dynamic DNS entry for your remote server. That way you can ssh to it using the dynamic DNS name, even if it changes its IP adress. Just do a web search for dynamic DNS and you'll find half a dozen providers.